# Opening close vote dialog on a close voted question causes the app to crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, close-dialog

When trying to open the close vote interface on an already (self) close voted question, the app tends to close itself*.

Steps to reproduce:

- Click close in the question menu
- Cast Close vote
- Wait for flag submitted feedback
- Click close in the question menu

Version 0.1.68

<sub>*crash</sub>

This not fixed for me as of version 0.1.70. Now, I am not receiving the flag submitted feedback after close voting.

Steps to reproduce:

- Click close in the question menu
- Cast Close vote
- Click close in the question menu

Comment: Your title hurted my brain! But, still...

Comment: Tongue twister title :)

Comment: Sounds like it's still not working on 0.1.70 but for a different reason. Open a new bug report, please.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent catch! Fixed in version 0.1.70 coming out tonight.

Comment: Umm.. Not really. Now, I am not getting any feedback on casting a close vote and the app is crashing if I open the close vie interface twice.